# Python - Reading from a file, any file

Tags: file

I want to make a function that reads from a txt file, thats given by the user on a function. I know how to open a specific file, on python, but I don't know how to make it any file on a function.

For example I want do something like this:
Read_board(irock.txt) --- irock.txt, can be any other fale, it's the argument that the function recieves. Read the line on the file and return it.

This is my final code

```
    def le_tabuleiro(txt):
        text = ((open(txt, 'r')).readline())
        print text
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Remove the quotes around `f`. That is, `open(f, "r")` not `open("f", "r")`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your quick answered, it worked.

Comment: @FranciscoKlogan: I doubt that "it worked" considering that your code attempts to read from `f` which is the file name, not the open file object. You should read from `ficheiro` instead. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read from the file object, not its name. Try this:

```
def read_board(f):
    ficheiro = open(f, "r")
    line = ficheiro.readline()
    return line
```

Also note that `f` is a string containing the file name so pass the variable unquoted to `open()`.

One other thing worth mentioning is that you can/should use a `with` statement to open the file. This will ensure that the file is properly closed once the function returns (or if there is an exception):

```
def read_board(f):
    with open(f, "r") as ficheiro:
        return ficheiro.readline()
```